# website performing slow once mysql connection RDS reached 50

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, amazon-rds, aws

Below the rds parameter group config, please help me to resolve this issue.
I am using 4 web server having 2 CPU and 8 GB ram and rds having 4 cpu and 16 GB ram.

Once the connection reached 50 site will stop responding.

```
join_buffer_size                        150.00 MB
read_buffer_size                        150.00 MB
read_rnd_buffer_size                    300.00 MB
sort_buffer_size                        150.00 MB
Total for max_connections=600           750.00 MB
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `.cfg/ini [mysqld]` section  consider using

```
max_connections=100  # since you are stymied at 50 connections
join_buffer_size=256K
read_buffer_size=128K
read_rnd_buffer_size=256K
sort_buffer_size=256K
```

the last 4 are allocated at connection and your values are over the top,
my recommendations are close to defaults suggested in refman.
`thread_cache_size=50`  would prevent most threads created thrashing.

Answer (score 0):

There may be many causes here are some suggestions:

**1) Check slow query log in mysql:**

https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/mysql/enabling-the-slow-query-log-in-mysql

**2) Change mysql driver in your application**

Even if you downgrade it, you can have better results. Change a major version if possible.

**3) Look for locks**

mysqladmin debug

It will dump a lot of information, including locks, but  you can get lock information by queries too:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-open-tables.html

Hope it helps